# How to return Oracle Custom Rec type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, odp.net

I have to return a single record, and the dba create a package that returns a custom record type. I can't find any help online. I hope you could please help me.

Here are the functions as defined in Oracle.
In C# I use ODP.NET 4

```
FUNCTION calcAcct(p_1  IN VARCHAR2, p_2 IN DATE) RETURN AcctRecType;
```

Here is how I get records back in SQL, just have a hard time with C#.

```
DECLARE
    myRec PKG_PORTAL.ACCTRECTYPE;
BEGIN
    myRec := PKG_PORTAL.calcAcct('P1',TO_DATE('03/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myRec.column1);
END;
```

Comment: 've you got output or?if you got error can you mention here!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    myRec PKG_PORTAL.ACCTRECTYPE;
BEGIN
    myRec := PKG_PORTAL.calcAcct('P1',TO_DATE('03/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy'));

    SELECT myRec.column1, myRec.column2 FROM DUAL;
END;
```